# How to get last Sunday of previous year, if we enter any date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Ex. If I enter today's date 2014-06-23 it should show me previous year's last Sunday date i.e. 2013-12-29. Should not use any procedure / sub-queries, it should be only a single query. Im using MySQL. Kindly help.

Comment: SELECT
MAX(user_joined_date)
FROM loyalty_fact
WHERE YEARWEEK( user_joined_date, 0 ) = YEARWEEK(LAST_DAY(ADDDATE(LAST_DAY('2014-06-20'),-365)),0) 
AND WEEKDAY( user_joined_date ) =6
AND user_joined_date <=  '2014-06-20'

Comment: the above query is the other one which we tried.. here user_joined_date is date column

Answer (score 0):

> This will return last year **Sunday** of Current Month

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 year) last_sun
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/39701)**

> This will return Last year last sunday

```
SELECT (DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 day))- INTERVAL (WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) - 1) * 7 DAY AS Sunday
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/39715)**

Comment: I tried this select ('2013-04-15' - interval dayofweek(2013-04-15) - 1 day) - interval (weekofyear(2013-04-15) - 1) * 7 day as SUNDAY; but getting NULL result.. is this is correct??

Comment: @user3766247 Actually you have missed single quotes in date.. Try this `select ('2013-04-15' - interval dayofweek('2013-04-15') - 1 day) - interval (weekofyear('2013-04-15') - 1) * 7 day as SUNDAY;` check fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/39726

Comment: thanks it worked and i got result as '2012-12-30' which is correct. But if I change the date in query as "select ('2012-06-06' - interval dayofweek('2012-06-06') - 1 day) - interval (weekofyear('2012-06-06') - 1) * 7 day as SUNDAY;" it gives me '2012-01-01' which is wrong.. pls help

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select (date(now()) - interval dayofweek(now()) - 1 day) - interval (weekofyear(now()) - 1) * 7 day
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon,

Can I have something like if it should ask to enter a date and if I enter any date it should show me its previous year's last Sunday date?

Comment: You can do this for any date by replacing `now()` with the date in question.

Comment: I tried this select ('2013-04-15' - interval dayofweek(2013-04-15) - 1 day) - interval (weekofyear(2013-04-15) - 1) * 7 day as SUNDAY; but getting NULL result